# Как правильно преобразовать массив

Tags: php, массивы, json

Подскажите, как правильно `json_encode`ить массив такого типа:

```
array(16) { 
   ["_edit_last"]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> string(1) "1" 
    } 
   ["_edit_lock"]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> string(12) "1511166264:1" 
    } 
   ["dev_photo"]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> string(3) "210" 
    }
   ["dev_fname"]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> string(8) "Петр" 
    }
    ["dev_sname"]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> string(12) "Петров" 
    }
    ["dev_position"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(20) "Копирайтер" 
    }
    ["dev_desc"]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> string(432) " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod praesentium impedit distinctio nulla laboriosam in perferendis ipsum quia illo placeat dolorem voluptatibus ducimus ex, rerum ab culpa saepe vero. Illo? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod praesentium impedit distinctio nulla laboriosam in perferendis ipsum quia illo placeat dolorem voluptatibus ducimus ex, rerum ab culpa saepe vero. Illo?" 
    } 
    ["dev_link_fb"]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> string(1) "#" 
    } 
    ["dev_link_vk"]=> array(1) { 
         [0]=> string(1) "#"
     }
    ["dev_link_instagram"]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> string(1) "#" 
    } 
    ["dev_skill_wp"]=> array(1) { 
         [0]=> string(1) "6" 
    }
    ["dev_skill_htmlcss"]=> array(1) { 
         [0]=> string(1) "7" 
    }
    ["dev_skill_opencart"]=> array(1) {
         [0]=> string(0) ""
     }
    ["dev_skill_javascript"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(0) ""
     }
    ["dev_skill_ps"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(1) "9"
     } 
    ["dev_skil_ai"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(0) "" 
    } 
}
 0
```

просто `json_encode` возвращает `null`

```
$link = !empty($_POST['link']) ? esc_attr($_POST['link']) : false;
$slug = $link ? wp_basename($link) : false;
$team_id = (int)$slug;
$team_id=(string)preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $team_id);
$result = get_post_meta($team_id);
return json_encode($result);
```

Comment: приведите код, который для данного массива возвращает `null`

Comment: и то есть если сделать `die(json_encode($result))` то будет пусто? не верю.